# Adding Context menu to DataTemplate Items in wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I Add the context menu Programatically where Conrol (DepedencyObject) are Created in Data Template in xaml?

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="sampleListBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code:

```
void Initilize()
{
     ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
     cm.Items.Add(new MenuItem());

     ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu( 
              // I am not geting the DepedencyObject as a parameter and 
              // depedency Object has to passed. 
              // My Qyestion is how to get the Stack pannel here.
     , cm);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `XAML` to assign ContextMenu to the `StackPanel`? And if you want to customize you `ContextMenu`, register to its `Loaded` event.

### Example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="samleListBox"
            ItemsSource="SomeCollection">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Loaded="OnContextMenuLoaded" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```